# Visual Studio Update 2015, many options for ASP.NET MVC project missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, and a lot of the configuration I was used to is missing or different. I'd like to know if these changes are due to something simple (like a package I need to install), or if it's something a little more complex.

I'm mainly using Visual Studio to create MVC apps from scratch, so before the update, I would create an empty MVC app with the "Add core references and folders for MVC" selected. Now, I can only create an empty MVC project with nothing pre-configured, or a fully scaffolded MVC app.

In the empty MVC project, there's no option to "Add Controller" when I right-click the "Controllers" folder I create. However, this option is available in the generated one.

The *Add New Item* menu is divided into Server-side and Client-side templates for the generated app, but it's divided into Code/Data/General/Web/etc. in the empty app. There's also an option to add an MVC View in the generated app, but there's nothing with Razor for the empty app. No .cshtml intellisense in the empty app, either.

There's a lot of functionality and options missing from the empty app that seem like they have to do with how the app is an MVC app, since they're available for the generated app. Is there a straightforward fix that will allow me to create an MVC app using Razor from an empty template?

Comment: Do you have Update 1 for VS installed?

Comment: Yes, that's the update that I just installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I was using the ASP.NET 4.5.2 Empty Template, and choosing the ASP.NET 5 Template solved the problem.